# Form array not saving input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, formarray

I have this form array:

```
this.chavesNfeForm = new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          chave: new FormControl(""),
        })
      ]);
```

And I use on my aplication like this:

```
 <form [formGroup]="chavesNfeForm" *ngIf="this.nfReferenciadaForm.value.referenciada==1" >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let chaves of chavesNfeForm.controls; let i = index">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label><i class="fas fa-key"></i> Chave NF-e </mat-label>
              <input matInput required formcontrolName="chave">
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </form>
```

So that I can have mutiple and dinamic forms as needed, having the user being able to add or remove as much as he needs.

However, when I try to output the value of the form for later use I get nothing, not a single value is stored on the form.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. (Currently using Angular 8 and Typescript)

Comment: chavesNfeForm must be a FormGroup

Comment: I need it to be an array, having it to be dynamic, since the user can have multiple chavesNfeForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using formControl instead of formcontrolName

```html
// With form control
<form
  [formGroup]="chavesNfeForm"
  *ngIf="this.nfReferenciadaForm.value.referenciada == 1"
>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let chaves of chavesNfeForm.controls; let i = index">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label><i class="fas fa-key"></i> Chave NF-e </mat-label>
            <input matInput required [formControl]="chaves.get('chave')" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Comment: Nope, the output still shows all the controls with empty values

Comment: can you try the 2nd example with the form control

Comment: Yep, still no inputs been shown

Comment: what happens if you remove  *ngIf="this.nfReferenciadaForm.value.referenciada == 1" condition

Comment: Oh, that's for another thing. There's a select above it that, if the option equals to 1, I open this form for the user. Removed just in case and no changes.

Comment: tried the code in my local env, and I can see the input fields, and the values can you create a stackblitz example or post the full ts code

Comment: Recloned and rebuild the project. The solution worked. Using the formControl got me to capture the inputs.